# How to know output type

Tags: shell, string

I've got this code:

```
(defun insert-random-uuid ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "uuidgen" t))
```

which produces a uuid that looks like this `ffc715d2-1e10-4faf-b1f6-f85cae88a7d7`. However, I believe it's throwing in a newline *and* that it isn't returning a string:

```
(stringp (insert-random-uuid))
```

which returns `nil`

So I find this at the EmacsWiki:

```
(defun chomp (str)
      "Chomp leading and tailing whitespace from STR."
      (while (string-match "\\`\n+\\|^\\s-+\\|\\s-+$\\|\n+\\'"
                           str)
        (setq str (replace-match "" t t str)))
      str)
```

which seems to handle both whitespace and \n. But of course `(chomp (insert-random-uuid)` gives an error, no doubt because `insert-random-uuid` is not returning a true string. So what is it returning, and how can I remove the newline? I tried various things to "cast" the output to string, but no luck. How can I get rid of this newline?

Comment: you wanted `shell-command-to-string`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `(type-of EXPRESSION)` to determine the type of an expression.

In your case you are confusing the value being inserted into a buffer by a function with its return value.

`shell-command` *inserts* the textual output of the command, but it *returns* the exit status of the command (which, of course, is an integer).

The simplest solution to your problem is probably to prevent the shell from generating a newline in the output in the first place. e.g.:

```
(shell-command "printf %s \"$(uuidgen)\"" t)
```

Comment: `shell-command-to-string` might be part of a solution too

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not obvious to me. As far as I could tell from the question, the problem the user had with their original code was that it inserted an extraneous newline. The only reason they were ever attempting to manipulate the return value as a string was because they thought it would help deal with that problem. With the problem taken care of at the shell command level, I presume there's no requirement to return a string.